# NLog - ASP.Net Web API Tracing

Tags: asp.net-web-api, nlog

Trying to get some basic ASP.NET Web API Tracing happening using NLog.

After a lot of searching the only documentation I could find is here: http://nlog-project.org/2010/09/02/routing-system-diagnostics-trace-and-system-diagnostics-tracesource-logs-through-nlog.html

The above isnt for the Web API but I have tried to adapt it, the problem seems to be in my Web.Config:

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.Web.Http.ApiController" switchValue="All">        
        <listeners>
          <add name="nlog" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="nlog" type="NLog.NLogTraceListener, NLog" />
    </sharedListeners>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

Any ideas why it's not working or references to an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes I have written an article on how to implement NLog as an `ITraceWriter` provider for Web API.

It was written against Web API RC but it should work fine with RTM as well: http://www.strathweb.com/2012/06/using-nlog-to-provide-custom-tracing-for-your-asp-net-web-api/

There is also an example on GitHub, by Dave Bettin - https://github.com/dbettin/webapi.nlog